# Laravel query eloquent how to get nearest time from db to carbon current time

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a schedule display system for ferries. problem is, this query currently finds the time in order which is put in sql. i want to find departure time closest to current time

```
            DB::table('ferries')->groupBy('ferry_name')->orderBy('ferry_name', 'desc')
            ->whereTime('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
            ->whereIn('schedule_type', ['Saturday','Weekday'])
            ->where('terminal_name', $terminal_name)->get()->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

how much closer? you can find time in a specific range

Example

```
DB::table('ferries')->groupBy('ferry_name')->orderBy('ferry_name', 'desc')
    ->whereTime('departure_time', '>', Carbon::now()->toTimeString())
    ->whereTime('departure_time', '<', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10)->toTimeString())
    ->whereIn('schedule_type', ['Saturday','Weekday'])
    ->where('terminal_name', $terminal_name)->get();
```

change the 10 to any number of minutes you want

I hope it's useful

Comment: yeah that works but different schedules different times so no specific range, just the closest time to current time so that gives me the next available schedule

Comment: @Navy you can use `->limit(1)` will return first closest result